# FORMS 10G DATA BLOCK

Tags: oracleforms

I am facing a problem in forms 10g with regard to data block. The fact is that when I am on a particular record of the block and that I call the `execute_query()` function to refresh the block the cursor moves back at the beginning and I have to go back to the record I was previously.

I would like to know how to avoid that I mean after the `execute_query()` function the cursor must stay on the current record and not to go at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to store the current item into a variable using `:system.current_item` or `:system.current_record` to fetch the item before `execute_query`. Once done, use `go_item()` to focus on the item retrieved earlier

Answer (score 1):

Use `:SYSTEM.CURSOR_RECORD` or `:SYSTEM.TRIGGER_RECORD` to find the current record number, then use `GO_RECORD` after you execute the query to return to that record.

Of course, that only works if you are retrieving the same number of records in the same order as the block currently displays.  Otherwise, you would need to store the primary key of your current record, then loop through the records using `NEXT_RECORD` until you find the one with the same primary key.

Answer (score 1):

first create this procedure as a program unit

```
            PROCEDURE SYNC_BLOCK
            -----------------------------------------------------------------------*
            --  Synchronizes the display of any scrollable block.
            --  After running an edit that loops through all records, this will
            --  restore the block's display so that the same top record is again
            --  at the top of the block's display.
            --  Blk is the name of the block.
            --  Rec_Num is the desired target current record.
            --  Top_Rec is the original Top Record of the block captured
            --  before the looping process began.
            (BLK      VARCHAR2,
            REC_NUM  NUMBER,
            TOP_REC  NUMBER) IS
            BLK_ID    BLOCK;
            TOP_NEW   PLS_INTEGER;
            REC_N     PLS_INTEGER;
            --
            Procedure Check_success is begin
            If not form_success then
            Raise form_trigger_failure;
            End if;
            End Check_success;
            Procedure Go_Rec(rec_num number) is begin
            Go_Record(Rec_num);
            Check_Success;
            End Go_Rec;
            BEGIN
            BLK_ID := FIND_BLOCK(BLK);
            IF ID_NULL(BLK_ID) THEN
            Message('  U72_GO_REC_SYNC_BLOCK: CANNOT FIND BLOCK '''||BLK||'''');
            Raise Form_trigger_failure;
            END IF;
            IF BLK <> :SYSTEM.CURSOR_BLOCK THEN
            GO_BLOCK(BLK);
            Check_Success;
            END IF;
            IF :SYSTEM.CURSOR_RECORD <> REC_NUM THEN
            GO_REC(REC_NUM);
            END IF;
            -- may need to re-set the display to the rows originally shown
            TOP_NEW := GET_BLOCK_PROPERTY(BLK_ID, TOP_RECORD);
            IF TOP_REC <> TOP_NEW THEN
            IF TOP_REC < TOP_NEW THEN
            IF :SYSTEM.CURSOR_RECORD <> TOP_REC THEN
            GO_REC(TOP_REC);
            END IF;
            ELSE
            REC_N := GET_BLOCK_PROPERTY(BLK_ID, RECORDS_DISPLAYED)
            + TOP_REC - 1;
            IF :SYSTEM.CURSOR_RECORD <> REC_N THEN
            GO_REC(REC_N);
            END IF;
            END IF;
            SYNCHRONIZE;
            -- Found that Sync caused focus change to different block. Fix here.
            IF BLK <> :SYSTEM.CURSOR_BLOCK THEN
            GO_BLOCK(BLK);
            Check_Success;
            END IF;
            IF :SYSTEM.CURSOR_RECORD <> REC_NUM THEN
            GO_REC(REC_NUM);
            END IF;
            END IF;
            -- can't go_rec to NEW record, so need to test here
            IF  :SYSTEM.LAST_RECORD = 'TRUE'
            AND REC_NUM = 1 + :SYSTEM.CURSOR_RECORD THEN
            NEXT_RECORD;
            Check_Success;
            END IF;
            --
            END SYNC_BLOCK;
```

second this below five lines of code do exact what you want

```
xx:=GET_BLOCK_PROPERTY('blk',TOP_RECORD);
xxx:=GET_BLOCK_PROPERTY('blk',CURRENT_RECORD );
go_block('blk');
execute_query();
SYNC_BLOCK('blk',xxx,xx);
```

please do not hesitate to contact me if you require further information